# Create a default style for a Textfield would fail

Tags: swiftui

I like to make a default style for my textfields. But some parts should be customizable from the view.

I be sure that I use not the correct way, because I got a error:

```
struct MaxTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    
    @State var icon: Image?
    @State var framesize: Int = 0
    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        HStack {
            if icon != nil {
                icon
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))
            }
            configuration
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(Color(UIColor.systemGray4), lineWidth: 2)
        }
        if(framesize > 0) { .frame(width: framesize) }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
    }
}
```

How can I add, that if be a framesize bigger then 0, that it would added?

Comment: You can use something like https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/conditional-view-modifier/ but beware of the potential issues with using an `if` modifier that breaks identify. Also, it appears here that you don't need `@State` -- that property wrapper is for when you have mutable state, which you don't have in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the majority of the custom View into a function makes it easy to implement what you are asking for.

```swift
struct MaxTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    
    @State var icon: Image?
    @State var framesize: Int = 0
    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        if(framesize > 0) { 
            makeView(configuration)
                .frame(width: framesize) 
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        } else {
            makeView(configuration)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        }
    }

    func makeView(_ configuration: TextField<Self._Label>): some View {
        HStack {
            if icon != nil {
                icon
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))
            }

            configuration
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(Color(UIColor.systemGray4), lineWidth: 2)
        }
    }
}
```